# iOS 5.1 Stops background music player

Tags: objective-c, ios, media-player, ios5.1

I have an app in the store that needs to play Music in background mode. Now with the iOS5.1 release, the music stops when the device is locked/moved to background.
I looked at the release notes and didn't find anything related.... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.plist your need to specify that your app will be playing audio in the background. For key "Required background modes" add a value "App plays audio". Note that raw name for that key is UIBackgroundModes, and the value you need to insert in that array is "audio".